# Image under a linear fractional transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers, circles

I've been asked to find and sketch an image of a set {z ∈ C* | Re(z) > 0} under a particular transformation T(z). The question changes where sometimes, Re(z) < 0 and the transformation T(z) changes but has a similar format, such as $-5/[(-4-9i)z-20i]$.

I'd like to know how to find the image of the set and how to sketch it. I know that the image of the set under this transformation is a circle but I'm not sure how to get the centre and radius.
I think the issue I'm having is, after working out what z is equal to in terms of w, and substituting w=u+iv, I would find x and y in terms of u/v and then from the lecture notes, I gathered that I should substitute x and y into an equation(inequality???) to solve for a centre and radius.

I however, don't have this equation to substitute my x and y for but I'm thinking the equation has to come from {z ∈ C* | Re(z) > 0}. The previous question also asked to find T(z1), T(z2), and T(z3) (z1,z2,z3 given in the question such as T(0) = ?, T(-5i) = ?), however, I don't think it has any correlation? I can't figure it out however and have been stuck for a while. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: As regards your second paragraph, the method you describe is correct. Make $z$ the subject, and in the case where $Re(z)>0$, you need to extract the real part of the expression in terms of $u$ and $v$ and set it $>0$. This gives you a Cartesian equation in tertms of $u$ and $v$ in the form of an inequality, but you can find the boundary by making it an equation, and then identify the relevant region in the $w$ plane. As regards your third paragraph, you need to be more specific because it’s not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

If $T$ is a Möbius transformation and we're only interested in the images of the upper and lower half-planes, we can use the circle-preserving property and plane Euclidean geometry to give a general strategy:

- Calculate any three values of $T$ along the real axis, such as the three points $T(0)$, $T(1)$, and $T(\infty)$; or $T(0)$, $T(1)$, and $T(-1)$.
- Find and draw the unique circle $C$ (possibly a straight line) through these three points.
- The image of either half-plane is one of the two regions bounded by $C$ (either the inside and outside of a Euclidean circle, or two half-planes defined by a Euclidean line). The image of the upper half-plane is the region containing $T(i)$, and the image of the lower half-plane is the region not containing $T(i)$.